# Where is the User model stored in django?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-forms

`User` is a model in `django.contrib.auth.models`.

I am currently developing a user registration and login system using in-built django authentication system.

I am using PostgreSQL as the underlying database instead of sqlite.

The migrations were successful to the point where corresponding tables were generated in my postgres database.

I am assuming that the table `auth_user` stores all the details of the registered user.

To test my database setup and authentication system, I am registering with a random user and check the `auth_user` table. In the table, I could find the username details for which I registered.

Next, I clear the contents of the `auth_user` table to start afresh.

But now when I register with the same username, I get the message `A user with this username already exists.` under the username field in my form. How is this possible? I cleared the contents of `auth_user` table in my Postgres database.

Then I create a separate view to display the contents of `User` model which belongs to `django.contrib.auth.models` and find that the username I registered earlier is being displayed even though the `auth_user` table is currently empty.

I am really curious about this. Am I missing something? Please clarify. I humbly apologize for the big write-up.

Comment: Are you sure you configured the database backend correctly? It looks like you might still use the `sqlite` somehow.

Comment: Yes the backend is configured correctly. It has been configured to postgresql with psycopg2. This made it even more confusing XD.

Comment: and if you remove the sqlite file, and restart the server, it does not create a new one?

Comment: Nope. It does not create any sqlite file because the database is postgresql.

Comment: How do you clear the contents of the auth_user?

Comment: Running a DELETE Script using pgAdmin4

Answer (score 0):

After spending a lot of time debugging through my entire setup, I figured out the issue. The settings.py was referring to a different database.

I had updated the environment variable which stored the database name. But for some reason the value updated by me is not being referred and the database of a previous project was currently being used. Nevertheless, this confirms that the User model is stored correctly in the database.

I checked it by finding out the database name through the `python manage.py shell` by doing the following:

```
In [1]: from django import db

In [2]: db.connections.databases
```

It displayed the database name currently being referred and the database name that was displayed was not the one intended.

The environment variable DB_NAME was not updated with the latest value by `settings.py` because I forgot to restart command line.

I apologize for the confusion. This was solely a configuration issue on my part.

Thank you [Andrey Nelubin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1420159/andrey-nelubin) and [Willem Van Onsem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/67579/willem-van-onsem) for spending your time on this.